# $f$ is a real function. What is the largest interval $S$ such that no open subset $I\subset S$ makes $f(I)$ constant?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be a real function.

We say a set $I$ is trivial if $f(I)$ is constant.

We say a set $S$ is purely non-trivial if no open subset of $S$ is trivial.

**Question:** Does there exist a largest $S$, such that all other pure non-trivial open sets $S'\subseteq S$?

**For example**, if $f(x)=x$, then $[0,1]$ is the largest purely non-trivial.

If $f(x)=x-0.5+|x-0.5|$, then $[0,0.5]$ is trivial and $[0.5,1]$ is a largest purely non-trivial.

**My try so far:** The following results might be correct:

Lemma 1: $S$ is purely nontrivial, open set $O\subset S$, then $O$ is purely nontrivial.

Lemma 2: Suppose open sets $S_1,S_2$ are purely non-trivial, then $S_1\cup S_2$ are purely non-trivial.

Lemma 3: The collection $\Omega$ of all purely nontrivial **open** sets is an algebra.

My stuck: if we can prove that $\Omega$ is a sigma field then I can say that the largest $S$ is simply $\cup_{S\in \Omega} S$ or its closure. However, $\Omega$ is **not** a sigma field!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but how about this:

Suppose that the largest $S$ exists and call it $S'$. Then Consider $f(x) = x$ on [0,0.25), 42 on [.25,.75], and x on (.75,1].

Then sets of the form $[0,0.25) \cup (.75,1] \cup \{z\}$ where $z \in [.25,.75]$ are clearly purely non-trivial.

If there existed a largest set $S'$, then it would at least have to contain all of the sets of the above form.

However, the union of all the sets of the above form is $[0,1]$. Contradiction?

Comment: Good point. So I edited (right after my initial post) that that largest set only need to contain all non trivial open sets. I hope this edit make the question more meaningful!

Comment: Then can't you take S' to be the union of all open, purely non-trivial sets? It's clear that this construction is maximal. It remains to show that S' itself is still purely non-trivial. Suppose A open $\subset$ S' is trivial. Then A intersects some S. The intersection of finite open sets is still open. This means the intersection is purely non-trivial. However, the intersection was a subset of A, so it is trivial. Contradiction?

Comment: Great comment! I missed the part "A intersects some S". Why A must intersect with a purely nontrivial S?

Comment: Because $S' = \cup S$ is the union of all open purely nontrivial sets by construction. So if A intersects S', then it must intersect some S